# Nextcloud Problem with memcache after Updates

Tags: redis, apc, nextcloud, php-7.4

I get a Problem with my Nextcloud everytime after Installing Updates. Everytime after Updating I can't access on my Nextcloud anymore. I get the Site, the System needs a Update.
After that I have try to install the Updates over the CLI by Hand:

```
sudo -u www-data php occ upgrade
```

But I get this Fault on the CLI:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'apc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/apc.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/apc.so: undefined symbol: zif_apcu_store), /usr/lib/php/20190902/apc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/apc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

An unhandled exception has been thrown:
OC\HintException: [0]: Memcache \OC\Memcache\Redis not available for distributed cache (Is the matching PHP module installed and enabled?)

It has been installed the PHP Version 7.4 (/etc/php/7.4/cli/config.php) in the past

Is there a Way to Upgrade the Nexcloud-System in future without any Work by hand on the CLI?
It is very frustrating everytime

Thanks for helping!

Comment: In Additon I have try to remove php7.4 and install php8.0 now to hope to resolve the Problem but I can't acces to the nextcloud Website more (505 Fault). I try to remove the php8.0 again an install the Php7.4 but still the same 505 Fault ont the Website. I think I crash all my System now OMG

Comment: Nobody any solution?